# How to find the time it takes for a ball to hit the ground?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am wondering if my answers to these two questions are actually correct. If they are not correct, then I'm looking to see if someone can show the work on how to get the answer to these homework review questions. For question $1$, the answer for the max height I got was $64$. For question $2$, the answer for the time it takes for the ball to reach the ground was $3$ seconds. I used the quadratic formula for question 2 after simplifying the equation and received $3$ seconds as my answer. Are these answers to my homework questions correct?

> The height of a ball thrown straight up from a building is given by $h(t)=-16t^2+32t+48$, $t$ seconds after it is thrown.
> $1)$ Find the maximum height of the ball.
> $2)$ Find the time it takes for the ball to reach the ground.

Comment: They are correct.

Comment: Unclear to me how the 1st question is to be attacked in the pre-Calculus world.  To determine the max height, it seems to me that you must first determine the time at which the height stops increasing.  In the Calculus world, this is done by computing $h'(t) = -32t + 32.$  From here, you then determine that $h'(t) = 0 \implies t = 1.$  Then, you (therefore) compute $h(1)$.  I don't know how this problem can be attacked without Calculus.  I suppose that you could attack the problem informally, by regarding the graph of $h(t)$ as an inverted parabola, and asking what the peak of the parabola is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$1)$ $h(t) = -16(t-1)^2+64 \le 64$ and the max height is $64$. For $2)$, $h(t) = 0 \implies (t-1)^2 = 4 \implies t-1 = 2 \implies t = 3$. So yes, you got it right.